# Make external website only accessible in sharepoint

Tags: iframe, embedded, external

I want to integrate an external website with an iframe (Embed Web Part) in a password protected company intranet (sharepoint) and make it only accessible there. So the public Domain should not be accessible from outside sharepoint. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the end user should not be able to write www.youdomain.com in any browser and see the result?

No that is not possible. The request and the rendering in the IFrame is the same as if the user had opened a new tab.

Comment: So what would be a other solution for that? Single Sign On on my website? Something with cookies? Any idea? In fact we want to create content from an external service but only for intranet users in sharepoint.